# Windows 7 Embedded always runs explorer.exe on boot despite registry being set to run nothing

Tags: windows-embedded-7

I have my value of `Shell` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` set as completely blank, but explorer.exe still runs on boot.

Why would this be?

Comment: You are attempting to disable explorer, so what problem are you trying to solve, by doing so?

Comment: It's not a problem... it's an embedded device. Many embedded devices have explorer disabled for many reasons

Answer (score 1):

The reason why explorer.exe always runs is because Microsoft has gone out of their way to make sure that a shell runs.  The reason they do this is because a shell provides for the presentation layer (OSI layer 7) of the Windows GUI.  You need to have a shell program if you are going to see a desktop.  If you boot into safe mode with a command prompt explorer probably isn't running then.

There are [alternative shell programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternative_shells_for_Windows) you can use instead of explorer.exe, but you must run something.

It is worth mentioning that explorer is not Internet Explorer.  That executable is iexplore.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i put a value for a not installed shell in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon.
Result was a blank black screen where only CTRL-ALT_DEL is possible.
So i can confirm that you are modifiying the correct key. But i didnt try an empty value.

Are you using the 64bit version of WES7 ?
Sometimes i am accidentally using the 32bit version of regedit and are wondering why my modifications for keys are not working.
Maybe this was your problem too ?

Answer (score -1):

You can us a program like [AutoRuns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to determine where `explorer.exe` is starting from, provided that you can run it since it is an embedded system.

You can uncheck the explorer.exe entry from within AutoRuns to disable it from starting.

*This utility, which has the most comprehensive knowledge of auto-starting locations of any startup monitor, shows you what programs are configured to run during system bootup or login.*

Comment: I mean the location of explorer.exe is certainly no mystery, it sits in `C:\Windows`... but that's not really relevant. I'm not sure you understood what I was asking though. I want explorer.exe TO NOT run.

Comment: You can uncheck the explorer.exe entry in AutoRuns to disable it from starting.

Comment: @jftuga That’s not going to work. Explorer is started by the OS, not via any of the autorun mechanisms.

Comment: You would think so right!?

Comment: @DanielB Right, it's launched through the shell property in the registry entry I mentioned. However, it appears to be completely ignoring that there is no entry in that part of the registry

Comment: Do all of us a favor and use autoruns....

Comment: @Moab Did you actually try it? It doesn’t help.